# django override auth login method

Tags: django, methods, authentication, overriding

I want to override `login` function in `__init__.py` of `django.contrib.auth`

I did steps:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^login/$', 'my_login'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request, user, backend=None):
   # do some stuff
```

**settings.py**

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #'django.contrib.auth',
    'my_auth_app'
   ]
```

But I feel it's the wrong approach.

Actually I want to get default `contrib.auth` with overidden `login` method

Comment: If you explained what "do some stuff" involves, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I think tha you should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/ at first time, here is your answer.

Comment: When login was complete the session_key is cycled, but I need to get previous session_key. I want to try add extra parameter to logged_in signal.

Comment: May be, override session middleware would best approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done this approach.

urls.py

```
# separate my custom login from django default auth
path('accounts/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'), 
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

views.py

```
def custom_login(request, user, backend=None):
    """
    modificated generic.auth login.
    Send signal with extra parameter: previous [session_key]
    """

    # get previous seesion_key for signal 
    prev_session_key = request.session.session_key

    """ 
        original code

    """
    # send extra argument prev_session_key 
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user, prev_session_key=prev_session_key)

# custom class-based view overriden on LoginView
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""

        # changed default login
        custom_login(self.request, form.get_user())

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

When I make custom_login based on default login(), I am afraid that it is no best approach, because i am copying a part of original code. Maybe it's better to use a decorator here?

Comment: Thank you. I struggled with customizing login url path until I realized that I need to put it before `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`

Comment: I tried putting login url before and after 'account/' , it still doesnt work

Comment: I was using django-two-factor-auth login instead of django.contrib.auth login, hence it did not work